# The best way to get result from activity without finishing result emitting activity, and again show the data for edit?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities, Activity A and Activity B. When I click on a button in activity A, activity B gets called for Result then some data is entered   in edittext of activity B and this text is sent as result to Activity A.Then on Activity A result is shown in TextView. Now again I want to edit the text in Activity B.

Is there any way to not to finish or recreate activity B so data will remain there when I switch back to activity B.

if needed I will post my code too.

Comment: You won't switch back to activity B, but you will create it again. Because from Activity B, you have pressed back button to come to A, so it's destroyed. As much i know, you can't keep it aside. You have to pass data to B through bundle every time.

Comment: I suggest moving on the fragment. Everything will be working

Comment: use intent to pass your data. or store into shared Preference.  what you do you want to with result.  are clear with your functionality?

Answer (score 0):

- If you return to ActivityA, ActivityB obviously will be destroyed. You need to pass those data again to ActivityB by `intent.putExtra(your_key, your_value);`
- Another turnaround solution is to store data to singleTon class.